# Thread Ownership of a mutex

Tags: c++, pthreads, c++14

According to several documentation examples the thread can't unlock a mutex unless it locked it explicitly. Here is an excerpt from man page for pthread_mutex_unlock at IBM.

> The pthread_mutex_unlock() function unlocks the mutex specified. If
>   the calling thread does not currently hold the mutex (via a previous
>   call to pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_trylock(), or
>   pthread_mutex_timedlock_np()) the unlock request fails with the EPERM
>   error.

Even the new C++ standard says something similar about the thread ownership, yet the following program was able to unlock a mutex locked on a different thread. On gcc & Linux systems the same behavior is seen both on pthread mutex as well as std::mutex (which I believe is implemented based on pthread_mutex anyway).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <pthread.h>

std::mutex stmutex;

pthread_mutex_t pthrmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void thread1(int i)
{
  stmutex.unlock();
  std::cout << "Un Locked in thread 1" <<  std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

void pthread1(int i)
{
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&pthrmutex);
  std::cout << "Un Locked Pthread mutex in thread 1" <<  std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

void thread2(int i)
{
  stmutex.lock();
  std::cout << "Locked in thread 2" <<  std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

void thread3(int i)
{
  stmutex.unlock();
  std::cout << "UNLocked in thread 3" <<  std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  try {
   stmutex.lock();
   std::cout << "Locked in main thread : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
   std::thread t1(thread1,1);
   t1.join(); 
   stmutex.lock();
   std::cout << "Locked in main thread after unlocking in thread1" << std::endl;
   stmutex.unlock();
   std::cout << "Un Locked in main thread " << std::endl;


   pthread_mutex_lock(&pthrmutex);
   std::cout << "Locked pthread mutex in main thread : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
   std::thread t2(pthread1,1);
   t2.join(); 
   pthread_mutex_lock(&pthrmutex);
   std::cout << "Locked Pthread mutext in main thread after unlocking in thread1" << std::endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&pthrmutex);
   std::cout << "Un Locked Pthread mutext in main thread " << std::endl;

   std::thread t3(thread2,1);
   t3.join(); 
   std::thread t4(thread3,1);
   t4.join(); 

  } catch (std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception In main thread: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything in my understanding of mutex "Ownership" ?

Comment: It's not because it's observed to work that it's not undefined behavior. To unlock an `std::mutex` without owning the lock is undefined behavior. As for the `pthread` part of the question, you never check any return codes.

Comment: Is there a reason you are still using p_thread rather than the new Standard Library stuff?

Comment: @JiveDadson The example uses both standard and pthread.

Comment: Why not just standard? Can the two be mixed legally? I don't know.

Comment: @JiveDadson. I am just using the standard. The example has both for illustrative purposes to demonstrate it is not just the standard implementation but pthread also exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I stripped out all the p_thread stuff and ran it under VC++. It throws an exception: `unlock of unowned mutex`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see that std::mutex::unlock does indicate that this is an undefined behavior. However pthread variation doesn't return an error during unlock() so return code checking or not the behavior is the same.

Comment: `std::mutex::unlock()`: _"The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the __behavior is undefined__."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock  Reasoning about UB is a waste of time.

Comment: @dors `pthread_mutex_unlock` returns an error code. *"If unsuccessful, pthread_mutex_unlock() returns -1 and sets errno to one of the following values:"* from, presumably, [the same source you used](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/ptmunlk.htm). It will return -1 and set `errno` to `EPERM`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes you are correct but I see that it doesn't return EPERM doing pthread_mutex_unlock. But I now I see why.  As Maxim mentioned the mutex should be initialized to PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP for pthread_mutex_unlock to check this and return the error. Otherwise it returns successful.  Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The request fails with the `EPERM` error only for mutexes created with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`.

See [`pthread_mutex_lock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) section RATIONALE:

> ...  while being able to extract the thread ID of the owner of a mutex might be desirable, it would require storing the current thread ID when each mutex is locked, and this could incur unacceptable levels of overhead.

I.e. initialize your mutex with `PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP`.

Example:

```
void locker(pthread_mutex_t* mutex) {
    if(int e = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex))
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_lock: (%d)%s\n", e, strerror(e));
}

void unlocker(pthread_mutex_t* mutex) {
    if(int e = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex))
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_mutex_unlock: (%d)%s\n", e, strerror(e));
}

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t a = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t b = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
    std::thread(locker, &a).join();
    std::thread(locker, &b).join();
    std::thread(unlocker, &a).join();
    std::thread(unlocker, &b).join(); // pthread_mutex_unlock: (1)Operation not permitted
}
```

Comment: Did you test it? Doesn't seem to make a difference in the behavior for the above example.

Comment: The example makes no verification that the pthread functions succeeds. Failures would not be apparent.